# WPF TextBox with StaticResource for Style and Text-Binding to property at ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, resourcedictionary

I stucked at followed issue since a few days, perhaps I have misunderstood something.

I create a ResourceDictionary with stylesettings for textboxes and add it to App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZeissVorbereitung">
<Style x:Key="ModernTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border CornerRadius="10"
                        Background="#353340"
                        Width="100" Height="30">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="1"
                                 Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 Padding="5"
                                 Foreground="#CFCFCF"
                                 x:Name="SearchBox"/>
                        
                        <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Text="Type new Entry..."
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   FontSize="11"
                                   Foreground="DarkGray"
                                   Grid.Column="1">

                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchBox}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then I create a textbox in a View and use the Style sucessfully:

```
<TextBox
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Width="100"
    Margin="0,5,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Style="{StaticResource ModernTextbox}"
    Text="{Binding AddNavigationTextField}"/>
```

In the ViewModel is the property for binding:

```
 private string _addNavigationTextField = "";

   public string AddNavigationTextField
   {
        get => _addNavigationTextField;
        set
        {
            _addNavigationTextField = value;
            OnProtertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Normaly the bindings works, but I dont know how to combine the Style-Resource with a dynamic Binding, so I could use multiple TextBoxes with the same Style but different bindings. Thank you for your help!

Comment: your code looks just fine, what is the problem to have another Textbox and another VM property ?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Perhaps you can help me out. Isn't that the place where a developer would define the styles that would affect elements in the rest of the app? Why are you adding that grid, textbox, and textblock with bindings in there?

Answer (score 0):

Try style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ModernTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CFCFCF"/>
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="#CFCFCF"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                 <Border CornerRadius="10"
                         Background="#353340"
                         Width="100" Height="30">
                      <Grid>
                           <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                           <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
                                         SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                         Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>

                           <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                      Text="Type new Entry..."
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                      FontSize="11"
                                      Foreground="DarkGray"
                                      x:Name="Watermark"
                                      Visibility="Collapsed">
                           </TextBlock>
                      </Grid>
                 </Border>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                          <Setter Property="Visibility"  TargetName="Watermark" Value="Visible"/>
                      </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I improve trigger, remove inside texbox and use part of standart style.